# Overriding Render to write an Excel file to the response hangs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am overriding `Render` like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var keyCheck = HttpContext.Current.Session["PaymentSearchResults"];

    if (_exportToExcel && keyCheck != null)
    {
        ExportToExcel();
        return;
    }

    base.Render(writer);
}
```

To download an Excel file which I'm adding to the response like this inside the `ExportToExcel` method:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(tempFileName, buffer);

Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.WriteFile(tempFileName);

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

However, the response is never getting back to the browser and so the browser just hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i use, in a button click event. works like a charm.

```
HttpContext httpCtx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

httpCtx.Response.Clear();
httpCtx.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
httpCtx.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
httpCtx.Response.Charset = "utf-8";

httpCtx.Response.WriteFile(filePath);

httpCtx.Response.End();
```

Comment: So I don't need to keep render from happening then? Just run this in the click (which is where I was setting `_exportToExcel`)?

Comment: Yup. It sends the file as an attachment with the original page. So you get to see the page as it was before clicking plus is starts downloading your file.

Comment: Scratch that, after removing the `File.Delete` to remove the temporary file, the file was downloaded. This currently appears to be working. Please stand by.

Comment: I copied this code straight from a working project that i'm in at the moment so something else must be going on. Try it from another workstation/browser i suggest. Is the excel very big?

Comment: Since you don't really know when the file is fully downloaded you can't delete it in your page cycle. I must admit i never delete anything automatically unless i absolutely have to. I could imagine throwing all the files in a temp folder on application start or something.